# Replace string with another string in the same list if string contains the other one

Tags: python, python-2.7

A list has a mixture of full names and their short names. I want to expand the short names to their full name in a list like below. Eg. Pollard should be changed to Kieron Pollard and Starc should be changed to Mitchell Starc.

```
players = ['Pollard', 'Kieron Pollard', 'Mitchell Starc', 'Pollard', 'Starc']

print(players)
for i, s in enumerate(players):
    for p in players:
        if len(p) > len(s) and s in p: # Different string
            players[i] = p
print(players)
```

Output:

```
['Pollard', 'Kieron Pollard', 'Mitchell Starc', 'Pollard', 'Starc']
['Kieron Pollard', 'Kieron Pollard', 'Mitchell Starc', 'Kieron Pollard', 'Mitchell Starc']
```

The above method works great. I want to know if there is a better and a efficient way of doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

Just have the actual name and its replacement in a dictionary and using List Comprehension reconstruct the player names by looking up the names in the dictionary.

The second argument passed to `names.get` method is the default value to be returned if the first argument doesn't exist in the dictionary.

```
names = {'Pollard': 'Kieron Pollard', 'Starc': 'Mitchell Starc'}
print [names.get(player, player) for player in players]
# ['Kieron Pollard', 'Kieron Pollard', 'Mitchell Starc', 'Kieron Pollard', 'Mitchell Starc']
```

Comment: `names = {p.split()[-1] : p for p in players if ' ' in p}`

Comment: @Kiwi player names can be three words sometimes

Comment: If the short name is always the last one, it's ok: `' ' in p` stands for at least two words, `p.split()[-1]` extracts the last one

Answer (score 1):

I would sort the players by their lengths and pass on the from the longest to the shortest - breaking the inside loop when ever getting to a containment.

Also, note that in the way you check the containment - "a" is in "ab". Make sure that this is what you want.

Comment: about the containment, yes I can be sure.